# Multi-Page vs Multi-PDF Loop problems

Tags: ms-access, loops

I have a form that contains multiple partners that share a "pool". The partners are listed on a subform. After I'm done entering the information, I want a button to run a report for each of the partners with their specific information. But since it's multiple partners and I need one report for each (which I then want to email), I want to use a Loop to go through each of the partners.

**EDIT1:** Added entire code for review. I do have Option Explicit in and I have compiled it as well.

```
Private Sub btn_Run_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "Select * FROM Cobind_qryReport WHERE PartPoolName = """ & Me.TopLvlPoolName & """"
Debug.Print "strSQL: " & strSQL

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

On Error GoTo Err_PO_Click

If MsgBox("Do you wish to issue the cobind invites?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirmation Required") = vbYes Then
rs.MoveFirst
Do While rs.EOF = False
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Cobind_rptMain", acFormatPDF,_
   "K:\OB MS Admin\Postage\CoBind Opportunities\Sent Invites\" _
   & rs!CatCode & "_" & rs!PartPoolName "Cobind Invite_" & _
Format(Now(), "mmddyy") & ".pdf"
DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Cobind_rptMain", acFormatPDF, ,_
, , " Cobind Invite", "Please find the cobind invite attached._
 Response is needed by " & [RSVP] & ". Thank you.", True
rs.MoveNext
Loop
End If

Exit_PO_Click:
MsgBox ("It didn't work")
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Exit Sub

Err_PO_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_PO_Click
End Sub
```

This should allow me to create a report for each record in my query, save it to my server, then open an email to send it out. Right now, it appears that the [PartPoolName] is hanging up the code because I'm getting a "Microsoft Office Access can't find the field "|" referred to in your expression." If I take out the [PartPoolName], it'll create a PDF with four pages (each page showing a partner), where I want to end up with four separate PDFs.

Comment: What is in `Cobind_qryReport`? Basically, there should be a primary key for each report you want to print, and you should be using that as your filter for the report. I see no reason to use `SELECT *` as the SQL statement for a recordset that you're walking when you're really only using one or two fields from the resultset. In your code as it stands, you use only `rs!CatCode` and `rs!PartPoolName` so to my way of thinking, it should be `SELECT CatCode, artPoolName` and nothing else. But neither of those look like a PK -- is it perhaps a composite PK (because it's a N:N join table)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you should do is add **Option Explicit** to the Declarations section of your module.

Then, from the Visual Basic editor's main menu, select **Debug->Compile [your project name here]**

Fix all the problems the compiler complains about.  I suspect one of the compiler's first complaints may be triggered by this section of your code:

```
rs.MoveFirst

Do While Recordset.EOF = False
```

Do you have two recordset objects open, or one?

After you fix everything the compiler complains about, try your revised code.

If you get runtime errors, show us the exact error message and which code line is highlighted.

If the part of your code you haven't shown us includes an error hander, you can disable that error handler like so:

```
'On Error GoTo Err_PO_Click
```

Error handlers are great for production to shield users from errors.  However, during development you really need to be able to identify which code line causes the error.

Alternatively, you can leave your error handler active and select Tools->Options from the editor's main menu.  In the Options dialog, select the General tab, then select the "Break on All Errors" radio button and click OK.  You can switch that option back to "Break on Unhandled Errors" after you finish your testing.

**Update**: *You wrote: Right now, it appears that the [PartPoolName] is hanging up the code because I'm getting a "Microsoft Office Access can't find the field "|" referred to in your expression."*

What is [PartPoolName]?  If it's a field in the recordset, you can reference its value as `rs!PartPoolName` If it's something else, perhaps a global variable, give us more information about it.

**Update2**: Whenever your current code completes without error, you will hit this:

```
Exit_PO_Click:
MsgBox ("It didn't work")
```

Can that be right?

**Update3**: This OutputTo statement is your issue now, right?

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Cobind_rptMain", acFormatPDF,_
   "K:\OB MS Admin\Postage\CoBind Opportunities\Sent Invites\" & _
   "Cobind Invite_" & Format(Now(), "mmddyy") & ".pdf"
```

Cobind_rptMain is a report.  It has a RowSource for its data.  You're calling OutputTo with that report 4 times (once for each of the 4 rows in the recordset).  Yet you expect 4 different versions of that report ... a separate report for each PartPoolName value?

Comment: One trick I use is to add a line of code: Resume to my error sections. I can Cntl-Break on an error message box, move to the Resume line of code and hit F8. The break should move to the line creating the error.

Comment: See Edit1 of my post. I put the full code there. I took out [PartPoolName] and it's giving me a PDF with four pages instead of four separate PDFs. For each difference in [CatCode], a separate PDF should be created.

Comment: RE: Do you have two recordset objects open, or one? I should have just one open.

Comment: It's basically this: I have four child records reporting into a parent record. For each of the child records, I need the report to be created showing its data only. Right now, what's happening is that all four child records are being put into the same report. I can't get it to loop for each record.

Comment: Update1: That was it! Filename created correctly.  
Update2: Yes, I plan on changing that when done. It was just to show me when it ran. Update3: It's actually for each CatCode (another field in the recordset), which is the particular "child" as it were. PartPoolName equals the LanJulM (the parent pool name). So Child1, Child2, Child3, Child4 are part of the LanJulM pool. I need a PDF for each child.

Comment: Still ... if you run this twice, why would you expect to get different data in the report? ---> `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Cobind_rptMain" ...`

Comment: Well, that's the part I'm missing and I'm trying to understand. I don't know where to tell it that for every change in CatCode, print the report and loop until all the CatCodes are done for this particular pool.

Comment: Let me clarify more: I thought that the recordset would pull the records needed, in this case, 4 records (one for each child). The recordset would then run the report for EACH record. Therefore, why wouldn't it create four different reports?

Comment: Take a closer look at the data source for your report.  There is no feature which says "if there's currently a DAO recordset open, inspect it and guess how Len might want the data filtered this time".

Comment: Read this link for OpenReport: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238032(v=office.12).aspx, paying close attention to the WhereCondition description.

Comment: Then read this link for OutputTo: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238050(v=office.12).aspx, paying close attention to the ObjectName parameter --- "If you want to output the active object, specify the object's type for the ObjectType argument and leave this argument blank."

Comment: I apologize if I offended you. I have nothing but respect for your help and it wasn't my intent. I will continue to look for answers using the links you provided. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No offense here, Len.  I just needed to tend to other business.  The larger point was ... use DoCmd.OpenReport with a WhereCondition which limits the report's data source to the rows you want ... then use DoCmd.OutputTo with ObjectName blank to output the active report object (which you filtered with the WhereCondition).  Looks to me like you can use the same approach for your DoCmd.SendObject

Comment: I see what you mean by the OpenReport, that's just brilliant. I'm just stuck on the Where condition. It has to isolate the data source down to one record. It's just beyond what I know right now.

Comment: Crystal Long created a detailed Access tutorial: http://www.accessmvp.com/strive4peace/ Chapter 6 deals with SQL.

Answer (score 1):

To finish off the fine work by HansUp visit a page on how to print a report for a single record and how to generate reports to attach to emails.  See the [Emailing reports as attachments from Microsoft Access](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/email/reportsasattachments.htm) page.